# In Linux 2.6 device driver model, what's the entry point of the creation of struct device?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

If a USB device driver is loaded, and at some time the device plugs in, then which part of the kernel will create struct device and register it?

Answer (score 1):

When the driver is loaded, the system calls the function, which you assigned in module_init. You will want to call there usb_register(struct usb_driver skel_driver), where skel_driver is a struct with pointers to methods servicing the device, like the probe method.

The probe method is the one which is called, when a new usb device is introduced in to the system. In this place you can fill your struct (usb_skel) with what you will need in the future, initiate a char device or whatever you do, when the device is introduced.

The system mostly won't create anything by itself, it has to have most of the structs prepared and filled with device specific data.

Please see [usb-skeleton in lxr](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.39.4/drivers/usb/usb-skeleton.c) for reference and learn to use it, besides read [writing usb drivers from LDD](http://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch13.pdf).

Cheers